# What does 'Cost to you or Amount Forgone' and 'Amount made good or from which tax deducted' mean?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

I am based in the UK and as such, I am required to report my tax affairs to HMRC.

I am currently completed a P11D Form (End of Year Expenses and Benefits Forms 2017-18) and I have come across the terms:

- Cost to you or Amount Forgone (£)
- Amount made good or from which tax deducted (£)
- Taxable payment or Relevant Amount (£)

What exactly do these mean?  I have all of my Expenses details to hand but not sure what goes into each box so to speak.  I can see that `Taxable payment or Relevant Amount (£)` auto populates, based on the other two's entries.

Any help, on this matter, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the p11d guide.
http://jamescowperkreston.co.uk/downloads/Payroll/p11d_guide_2017_12_16.pdf

Comment: Link only answers may rot over time. Please add a quote that has the relevant explanation from the source.